# Printing FullCalendar with header on every printed page

Tags: javascript, html, css, fullcalendar-scheduler, fullcalendar-5

I'm using FullCalendar in an ASP.Net razor page. When printing I want to have a header (that includes title and logo) appearing on every printed page. What I currently have done is to have the header appearing fine on fist page but on the second and consecutive ones it appears on the top but overlays the calendar. I'm using CSS styling like so:

```
 @@media print {
      div.divHeader {
          position: fixed;
          top:0;
          right:0;
          margin-bottom: 150px;
      }
 }
```

It looks like on the [image of FullCalendar print issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONp0h.png) The red circles are the spots where the title and the logo appear on the second page. Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: I'd guess you need to put the calendar into a container which (in the print CSS) is positioned so its top starts at the point where the header finishes (i.e. 150px in your case). print CSS is a bit of a fiddly beast though.

Comment: @ADyson That would only affect the first page (start of calendar). The problem is the actual calendar element just follows through to the next print page(it doesn't get split in two) and doesn't account for the elements that appear on every page, it just gets displayed on top of them.